# Installing Perl's mysql-dbd module without internet access

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I need to be able to read/write to a mysql database using Perl. On all previous servers I have been able to use ppm-shell do download and configure the DBI module for mysql (mysql-dbd I think). However on one particular server, I don't have internet access.

Is there an easy way to get this installed? I'm on Windows 2008 Server by the way. I'm not brilliant at Perl either so if anyone can give some easy to understand instructions I'd really appreciate it

Thanks

Comment: Strawberry or ActiveState Perl?

Answer (score 1):

Get the module. ( this can help: http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=PPM_Repositories)

and do:  ppm install FILE.ppd

Comment: Thanks, I'm struggling to find a compiled version to be honest. I have the source code though, guess it's a case of trying to compile it manually, resolving dependencies etc. Urgh... :)

Comment: Is this right? In trying to install it I've had to install nMake and miniGW C compiler, install MySQL, and now it's expecting a running mySQL server on the box I'm trying to build on. I don't think PPM-SHELL needs a running MySQL server to install the module does it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Download the module from here http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/PPMPackages/10xx/

install via the command line:

```
ppm install filename.ppd
```